# What to use to replace deprecated Date.hours method in kotlin and java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to convert my device's time to UTC timezone. I am using Date library but looks to be deprecated.

```
val date =  Calendar.getInstance().time
date.hours = selectedHour //deprecated
date.minutes = selectedMinute // deprecated
return (Date(date.time - Calendar.getInstance().timeZone.getOffset(date.time))
```

I tried using Calendar and the Joda Time library, but not able to adjust timezone with them.

What library can I possibly use?

Comment: Use java.time, or the JODA library if you can't do that.  Never, ever, ever use java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar.

Comment: You can't "convert" a Timezone to UTC. Did you mean "convert time"?

Comment: Documentation: "*... **Deprecated.**
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, int hours).*"

Comment: java.util.Date objects don't have a time zone. They correspond to an instant in time that doesn't care whether you are in New York or Paris. Therefore, you cannot hope to convert a Date object "from a timezone to another timezone", since it is the same Date regardless of whatever time zone you might have meant to use. Which is admittedly a confusing notion to non-experts of datetime representations. Which is why it is better to use java.time classes, and its LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime, depending on what you're trying to deal with.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, I edited the question. changing the time to different time zone

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this?

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute)
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I am able to set different times using the `Calendar`. but not able to change the timezone from the `Calendar` instance.

Comment: If you want an instance where you can change the timezone at will maybe you can create your own GregorianCalendar instance.